# systemd: how do I view journals with journalctl without switching to root on CentOS 7?

Tags: centos, systemd

If I run journalctl as nonroot, I would get the following message:

```
No journal files were found.
```

But switching to root, or using sudo gives me the journal.

How can I view journals without switching to root (e.g. which group should I add myself in)? Cannot find it in the documents.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Can you explain? I can view journal on Arch Linux as I'm in wheel group, I don't know why RedHat does not want it to happen...

Comment: Well, I am always happy to be proved wrong. It means I learn something :)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I got that to work (on centOS 7) by adding my user to the *systemd-journal* group:

```
sudo usermod -a -G systemd-journal bob
```

bob is now a member, log out, log in and:

```
id -a bob
uid=1000(bob) gid=1000(bob) groups=1000(bob),190(systemd-journal)
```

And now it works:

```
$ journalctl
-- Logs begin at Mon 2015-04-06 09:50:36 BST, end at Thu 2015-04-09 20:20:16 BST. --
Apr 06 09:50:36 localhost.localdomain chronyd[941]: Can't synchronise: no majority
Apr 06 09:50:36 localhost.localdomain chronyd[941]: Selected source 91.206.8.70
Apr 06 09:51:07 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Time has been changed
```

I found this:

http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-journald.service.html

and this:

http://0pointer.de/blog/projects/journalctl.html

Comment: Great, I found adm group also works as shown [here](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/System_Administrators_Guide/s1-Using_the_Journal.html)

Comment: adm and systemd-journal don't work for me. I've verified that I'm a member of both, but still no journalctl (unless I run with sudo)

Comment: Mark, what is your operating system and version?

Comment: I've got the same thing as @MarkLakata now on a fresh Debian 8 (jessie) system. Tried groups adm, sudo, and systemd-journal, and exit/login to refresh groups but still need "sudo journalctl".

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: Don't forget to logout and in again. Starting a new terminal isn't enough.