# Journald: give users access to specific unit's logs

Tags: syslog, systemd, journald

I'm taking care of a server (Debian Jessie) that several developers use for deploying and managing their work.

Now there is a script on this server (managed by one of the developers) that does some regular maintenance stuff and therefore should run all the time.

I added that script as a systemd service so that it automatically restarts if it should ever crash.

```
[Service]
ExecStart=...
Restart=on-failure
StandardOutput=syslog
StandardError=syslog
SyslogIdentifier=maintenanceScript
User=maintainer
Group=devGroup

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The script itself works absolutely fine, but what I would like to improve is how the logs can be accessed. The script makes some console outputs from time to time and systemd does what I told it to do - it puts the console output into syslog.

But although the script runs under the account of the maintaining developer (verified using `ps`), I can only access the logs via `journalctl` when I'm logged in as root.

```
journalctl -u maintenanceScript
```

works perfectly fine as root and prints all log entries.

However, I would like the maintainer to be able to see those log entries aswell - but not necessarily see all other log entries in syslog (all I found so far says to add the users that should be able to access some sort of global logs to the journal admin group - but that would give him access to all global logs).

Can I configure journald to give some specified users access to global logs of some specified units?

Comment: We've had [this question](http://serverfault.com/q/717725/126632) before, with no answer. I would suggest that this is something you would want to propose as a feature to the systemd developers.

Comment: Sorry for the duplicate then, seems I missed that question.